# Ruby migration: convert an Excel-file into XML using a gem

Tags: ruby, excel, rubygems, migration

**Start**: an excel file (XLSX) containing customer data. **Result**: an XML file that a CRM system can import. **Tools**: Command Prompt, Ruby gem move-to-go. 
I'm following a step-by-step guide and have done steps 1-9. I need help with steps 9-12.

6. In command prompt: cd (Change direction) to folder where you want to put the migration folder.
7. Enter this command move-to-go new MigrationFolder excel (or other list-source).
8. Now a folder named “MigrationFolder” is created **COMMENT: The folder came with several files already included, File B was one of them. I moved File A here manually, not through command prompt.** (Picture 1).
9. Enter the folder. Enter the command cd MigrationFolder.
10. Open up the ruby file “Converter.rb”, this is the place where you do the mapping of the fields. **COMMENT: There's no file with that name in the folder, however I was able to find the file in their Git. I copied and pasted the code to a text editor and modified it to suit my excel file A.**
11. Now that you are done with your mapping, you want to run the conversion. **COMMENT: After I thought I was done with modifying the file, I pasted the code from text editor to command prompt as a whole.**
12. Enter the command move-to-go run. Now Ruby maps the source-file data with the converter file you edited. Which results in a XML file that contains the fetched data and that the CRM-system can read.**COMMENT: It resulted in a zipfolder containing an XML-file with data from File B, not A although I wrote the filename for it.**

    - How do I go about converting my excel file into XML (in a zipfolder) with Ruby gem move-to-go?
    - Do I have to change any fields in the excel file?
    - Do I need to map data? If yes, how?

**All files**: https://github.com/Lundalogik/move-to-go

**Original code**: https://github.com/Lundalogik/move-to-go/blob/master/sources/excel/converter.rb

**My modified code**: https://github.com/mr-pinkman/repo/blob/master/code

**Step-by-step guide**: https://github.com/Lundalogik/move-to-go/blob/master/step-by-step.md

Please help a rookie (who wants to learn) out!
*I'm willing to pay for someone to teach me by demonstrating this through Skype and Remote Assistance or similar software. My hair is starting to fall out.*

[image]

Comment: You need to provide some code and at least the url of the guide you are following. I recommendo to create a git repo in github or gitlab and share it in order to help you.

Comment: You should link to the gem you are using.

Comment: @Kris https://github.com/Lundalogik/move-to-go

Comment: @hernanvicente I've added links now!

Comment: "Enter the folder. Enter the command cd MigrationFolder." - Are you having a problem with this step because this is a shell command and depends on which operating system you are using, Windows, Mac, Linux etc...

Comment: Thank you @Kris ! I’m on Windows 10. I’ve converted the file to XML now BUT haven’t been able to connect the primary and secondary keys. So what I’d like to know now is how I connect the two columns in two different sheets to their respective primary keys in the first sheet.